# Rehashing /etc/shadow. Can I force NIS users to change password?

Tags: password, administration, pam, nis

I'm currently migrating a CentOS environment to a Debian one. The users log in over the network using NIS. I was hoping to copy `/etc/shadow` from my old server to my new one so that we can offer continuity to the users. I discovered two problems with it:

- **User ID conflicts** This is easily resolvable by adding 500 to the UIDs in the CentOS `shadow` file since CentOS started UIDs at 500 while Debian starts them at 1000.
- **Different password hashes** This is what's killing me. It seems CentOS hashes its passwords with `md5` while Debian uses `sha-512`. I would like to have the users be able to log in to the system without having to consult me.

An acceptable solution I found after some Googling was as follows:

```
passwd -d uname
chage -d 0 uname
```

The first line sets an empty password for the user `uname` so they can login directly. The second line causes `uname`'s password to expire so that they're forced to change it on next login. I figure this is a good enough compromise.

This is all well and good if the user logs in on the server. It does not work if the user attempts NIS authentication from a different box. They still get the message of "Password change required" but it's immediately followed by "Authentication Token Manipulation Error"; which, I'm guessing, is due to the fact that the password change is attempted via `passwd` rather than `yppasswd`. So this is the pickle I'm currently in. How can I achieve continuity without awkwardly forcing the users to first log in on the server?

---

**EDIT**

- [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-fedora-linux-upgrading-password-hashing/) is similar to what I'm talking about; except it makes no mention of NIS.
- [This](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.admin/nis-password-change-forcing/471261) seems to suggest that it's actually impossible. Can anyone refute that or confirm it?

---

**EDIT 2**
I just noticed that when users try logging in on the server, they can do so normally without error messages. On a different box (to test NIS), I switched to root then tried `su`'ing into one of the NIS users. It succeeds while giving me a warning that says "Authentication failed (Ignored)". I'm guessing this comes from the PAM policy chain.

Comment: The handling of password hashes is not _that_ different among Linux distributions, you should have looked at the mechanisms used (and how to represent which has is in use). AFAIU, some use a `$x$` prefix to represent the hash by a number `x`, so perhaps just adding/correcting that would have been enough.

Comment: Interesting note. The CentOS release was, however, ancient (I think <=5) so it used `md5` rather than Debian's `sha-512`: the Debian hashes are significantly longer and the method therefore didn't work when I tried.

Comment: @vonbrand After some reading, I found that the `$x$` actually refers to the hashing _algorithm_ So it stands to reason that if the `$x$`'s are different between 2 distros then they are using different hashing algorithms and (obviously) producing different hashes that can't just be fixed by changing `x`. More info on the numbering of algorithms [here](http://scottlinux.com/2011/06/25/upgrade-red-hat-centos-password-hashing/)

Comment: Are the passwords actually a problem? Debian should support CentOS's hashes. It's only the other way round that might be a problem: supporting newer hashes on an older distribution. If you do nothing, are the users able to log in? If they aren't, what error messages appear to the users and in logs?

Comment: @Gilles I actually "did nothing" and the users weren't able to log in. They get a normal "Authentication Failure" error as if they'd typed a wrong password. Interestingly enough, when they try logging in on the server, it works! Updating the question...

Comment: What OS(es) are the clients running?

Comment: All (server and clients) Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Isn't NIS a gaping security hole?

Comment: @DeerHunter in what way? I'm not allowing NIS over WAN. I'm talking about networked computers in an office.

Comment: @JosephR. - if you are not afraid of insiders and if your network is airgapped from the world outside, you may be OK (though [NIST](http://www.nist.gov) does not recommend it). Frankly speaking, you're inviting trouble with passwordless logins.

Comment: @DeerHunter I see what you mean. I thought you were referring to NIS in general not in this specific case. You do have a point, of course, but it's not that much of a concern to me as the people working in the environment I'm talking about are pretty much Linux-illiterate and wouldn't dream of trying to log in to their machines before I declare that "things are ready"

Comment: @JosephR. the hash numbers depend on libc implementation. At least for Glibc, it should be pretty much constant - see `man 3 crypt`. Note that blowfish hashing is borrowed from OpenBSD (IIRC) and may not be available everywhere, rather it was a standalone patch (which was widely used though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't a matter of re-hashing passwords at all. All I needed was to modify my old `/etc/group` so that it has group IDs starting with 1000 and the users could log in easily using their old passwords as some commenters have guessed.